# Passing JSON keys as String containing a range of numbers

Tags: java, json

I am trying to have a set of keys to point to a value.
For example the key 0 is to point to the value "EXAMPLE_1" 
keys 1,2,3,4,5 is to point to the value "EXAMPLE_2"
and keys 6,7,8,9,10 is to point to the value "EXAMPLE_3"

This is the JSON structure I came up with (which will exist in an external file).

```
{
  "0" : "EXAMPLE_1",
  "1,5" : "EXAMPLE_2",
  "6,10" : "EXAMPLE_3"
}
```

Using following code to read and fetch correct value.

```
private String getValue(String count){
    Map<String, String> map = // code to fetch data from the file and get above map. Works.

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();

        String[] keysInRange = key.split(",");

        if(Arrays.asList(keysInRange).contains(count)){
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

This technically works but is there a better way to do this.

Looking to improve the JSON structure.
Finding it silly to be passing in the keys in this manner.
Note that the keys would be a single number or always in a range.

Answer (score 1):

You could try below. This is assuming, Keys in range are like this 1,2,3,4,5 for 1,5

```
private String getValue(String count){
    Map<String, String> map = // code to fetch data from the file and get above map. Works.

    If(map.containsKey(count)){
     return map.get(count);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();

            if(key.contains(","+count) || key.contains(","+count+",") || key.contains(count+",") ){
              return value;
            }      
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your JSON structure to an array of elements:

```
{[ {
     "name": "EXAMPLE_1",
     "from": "0",
     "to": "0"
   },
   {
     "name": "EXAMPLE_2",
     "from": "1",
     "to": "5"
   },
   {
     "name": "EXAMPLE_3",
     "from": "6",
     "to": "10"
   }
]}
```

and parse them with a JSON parser like Jackson oder GSON in data objects like

```
class Example {
    private String name;
    private int from;
    private int to;
    // ommitted getters & setters for brevity
}
```

Your method then becomes (using Java 8+ and the streams api):

```
private String getValue(int count) {
    Set<Example> examples = ... //  code to fetch data from the file

    Optional<Example> match = examples.stream()
            .filter(example -> example.getFrom() >= count)
            .filter(example -> example.getTo() <= count)
            .findFirst();

    // or return the Optional<Example> directly
    return match.map(Example::getValue).orElse(null);
}
```